# Deploying Qt applications in Linux properly

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have written an application using Qt and I am trying to deploy it. I built my application it and tried distributing it, but I ended up having to build Qt statically so that users don't need to install Qt's libraries just to run my application. The only problem is that the fonts are broken, and images don't load.

To statically build Qt, I did this:

```
./configure -static -release -ltcg -optimize-size -no-pch -prefix "/home/myuser/Qt/5.11.1-static" -skip webengine -nomake tools -nomake tests -nomake examples -fontconfig
make -j4
make -j4 install
```

There was then the issue of fonts not working. I kept getting the error "QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory (Qt install directory)/libs/fonts", so I copied the dejavu fonts folder on my system to a folder called "fonts" in my program's directory and created a Bash script that set QT_QPA_FONTDIR to the new font directory. This made the error go away and made the text on my application visible, but when a password is being entered blank characters are displayed instead of asteriks or any other characters. Additionally, images do not show. I have a folder in the same directory as the application called "images" with my images inside, so I did this:

```
QIcon home("(program directory)/images/home.svg");
QIcon vpn("./images/vpn.svg");
ui->tabWidget->setTabIcon(0, home);
ui->tabWidget->setTabIcon(1, vpn);
```

The images do not show, but they do if the program is built using dynamic Qt. I tried both the full path and using ./ to refer to the current directory, but neither one results in the image appearing.

Comment: "to avoid having Qt's libraries" -- if your application gets built using Qt, then Qt would logically be a dependency. This does not make any sense.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I mean that users should not have to install Qt libraries just to run my application, and the required libraries should be statically linked, hence the whole point of my question. I will revise that sentence.

Comment: This is not really how Linux is fundamentally designed to be used. You're fighting to swim upriver. A losing proposition. All major Linux distributions have a package manager that tracks package dependencies. All you have to do is specify that your application requires Qt, and prepare a package for it, and then when installed, if Qt is not installed the package manager will automatically do it. If you insist on this kind of a distribution approach, the current technology for doing something like that involves containers and virtualization, which is a fairly advanced topic.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am building it statically because it is recommended from the Qt docs. "Static linking is often the safest and easiest way to distribute an application on Unix since it relieves you from the task of distributing the Qt libraries and ensuring that they are located in the default search path for libraries on the target system". Are you suggesting that I instead use dynamic linking for Qt? I am just looking for the most reliable way to do this, as it's my first time releasing a Qt application that must be usable on lots of systems.

Comment: I'm not sure what those Qt docs are referring to, but if you spend a few minutes looking at all the Qt-based software that's already in your Linux distribution, you will find that they will all, without exception, dynamically link with Qt libraries, and with all other libraries. There's nothing special about Qt that makes it different than any other software library. Static linking is only used in very narrow, specialized exception cases. Run of the mill software dynamically links with all the libraries it uses.

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51438780/1217285) is my answer to a somewhat similar question where I tried to provide a brief overview of available options for software deployment in the Linux world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, the way my company packages the Linux build of its Qt app is with the dynamic libraries, as shown in the attached screenshot.  Note that the actual executable (shown as "MyApp" in the screenshot, which I have doctored a bit to protect the innocent) is located inside a "bin" sub-directory along with all of the necessary shared-library files.  In the main directory is a short shell script ("MyApp.sh") that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset QT_PLUGIN_PATH   
appname=$(basename "$0" .sh)
dirname=$(dirname "$0")
cd "$dirname/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
./$appname "$@"
```

... the user is expected to run the MyApp.sh script, which will set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable appropriately and then run the executable file.

It's not the most elegant thing in the world, but it gets the job done (much like Linux itself, heh).

[image: Screenshot of Linux distribution file tree]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I ended up just deploying the application with dynamic Qt and making the required libraries dependencies of the package, since only 3 Qt libraries were required