# application compiled with qmake does not run if compiled from console but runs if compiled from QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have developed an application using QT (5.11.2) and QtCreator.

When I compile and run the application directly from QtCreator everything works fine in both, debug and release build.

I can also start the application from the console if it is build using QtCreator's "build" button.

However, if I try to build it from the console it does crash... I tried to compile it in debug mode to see if it throws any exception but I have very little experience with debugging right in the Linux shell.

The following commands were used to build the application:

```
qmake CONFIG+=debug  myProject.pro
make
gdb myProject
(gdb) run
```

That is the output:

```
Starting program: /home/.../myProject 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffedc48700 (LWP 30355)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe2c70700 (LWP 30356)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe246f700 (LWP 30357)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe09d7700 (LWP 30359)]
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
terminate called without an active exception

Thread 1 "myProject" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

I do not understand the error message.

Some things I have noticed:

- The application is compiling
- The application starts to run. The first
  couple of lines are executed
- I have not touched any build settings in QtCreator to the best of my knowledge
- the application is not crashing when the warning message `libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile`
   appears... so I guess it is not related to that.

My main question are:

- Why is it possible that a application runs fine when compiled from QtCreator but crashes when compiled via the terminal?
- Are there any build options which are by default set in qmake when someting is compiled from QtCreator?
- How do I have to proceed with this error? I do not know what the next steps should be since everything works fine when I'm using an IDE like QtCreator.

**EDIT:**

I have read the suggested question and the `Qt for Linux/X11 - Deployment` help page.

I tried to run the application using a bash file which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
appname=`basename $0 | sed s,\.sh$,,`
echo appname = $appname

dirname=`dirname $0`
tmp="${dirname#?}"

if [ "${dirname%$tmp}" != "/" ]; then
dirname=$PWD/$dirname
fi
echo dirname = $dirname

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$dirname
echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

echo " "
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$dirname/$appname "$@"
```

which is named exactly like my application with a `.sh` extension (`myProject.sh`).

Additionally I have run the `ldd ./myProject` command which lists the following dynamic libraries:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6edaf000)
    libQt5Charts.so.5   => /home/***/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Charts.so.5 (0x00007ff61912f000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5  => /home/***/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007ff6188eb000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5      => /home/***/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007ff6180ee000)
    libQt5Core.so.5     => /home/***/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007ff617994000)
    libstdc++.so.6      => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff61760b000)
    libm.so.6           => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff61726d000)
    libgomp.so.1        => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007ff61703e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1       => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff616e26000)
    libc.so.6           => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff616a35000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff619b70000)
    libpthread.so.0     => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff616816000)
    libGL.so.1          => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007ff61658a000)
    libz.so.1           => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff61636d000)
    libicui18n.so.56    => /home/***/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007ff615ed4000)
    libicuuc.so.56      => /home/***/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007ff615b1c000)
    libicudata.so.56    => /home/***/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007ff614139000)
    libdl.so.2          => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff613f35000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff613d33000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0    => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff613a1d000)
    libGLX.so.0         => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007ff6137ec000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0  => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007ff613536000)
    libpcre.so.3        => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ff6132c4000)
    libX11.so.6         => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ff612f8c000)
    libxcb.so.1         => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ff612d64000)
    libXau.so.6         => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff612b60000)
    libXdmcp.so.6       => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff61295a000)
    libbsd.so.0         => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007ff612745000)
    librt.so.1          => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff61253d000)
```

I have now copied all seven listed libraries from `/home/***/Qt/5.11.2/?` to the folder where my shell script and my executable is located.

Unfortunately, all of these steps did not solve my issue... therefore I either did something wrong or this is not the problem.

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142689/deploying-qt-applications-in-linux-properly

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the link. Unfortunately, this was not enough information to solve my issue. I have edited my question in order to give more informations

Comment: Why not google "how to debug with gdb" ? For example, the first command you should enter would be `bt` to see the call stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It could have been that easy. calling the `bt` command to see the call stack showed my exaclty what was necessary.